# OS X Screensaver: Retina Thumbnail Image

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, screensaver

I'm developing a screensaver for OS X using Xcode's screensaver template. By inspecting the package contents of system screensavers, I've found that the thumbnails used in the System Preferences list of screensavers are derived from two files in the screensaver bundle:

```
thumbnail.png (90x58)
thumbnail@2x.png (180x116)
```

I have created two images of these sizes and placed them in my screensaver bundle. However, the System Preferences panel on my retina screen appears to load the non-retina asset. Here is a screenshot of the System Preferences panel next to a QuickLook preview of the `thumbnail@2x.png` image:

[image]

---

I'm out of ideas. Anyone know what could be causing this and how I can stop it? Things I have tried:

1. Using tiffs instead of PNGs. -- Same result.
2. Naming the retina-sized asset `thumbnail.png` -- Same result.
3. Turned off "combine high-resolution artwork" in Xcode's build configuration. -- Same result.
4. Deleting the thumbnail assets altogether. Interestingly, the System Preferences panel does not go back to drawing a default thumbnail icon. Instead, it draws an empty white rectangle. This led me to believe there might be caching going on, so I spent some time trying to find where that would be. Cleared preferences, etc.

---

## Oddities

If you inspect a system screensaver's package bundle, you'll find that the two thumbnail files don't report dimensions in the Finder. And if you open them with Sketch, they BOTH appear as 90x58 to that app. (Although Photoshop shows the @2x asset as 180x116). The thumbnails from the system screensavers have the gloss effect already applied, whereas my thumbnail gets that effect automatically even though the image asset does not contain it.

I'm starting to think there's something fishy about the way the panel loads/draws these images. Maybe somebody knows something I don't?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Even if I change the DPI and remove the 1x thumbnail, it seems to rescale to half size and then stretch to fill 2x, which is absurd.

Comment: I actually tried using a system screensaver thumbnail resource, and it gets mangled when it's in my screensaver, so it's a configuration issue, not a content issue, it seems.

Comment: Yep. I never found a solution. I think the problem is in the OS X preference pane.